# WSL2 using pip with anaconda environment to install packages

Tags: pip, anaconda, wsl-2, anaconda3

I am on a Windows machine running WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04 (fresh install) afterwards I installed Anaconda with `wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` and `bash Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`. I also update my conda by running `conda update conda`

However when I create a new conda enviroment (`conda create --name=test-env python=3.8`) and activate my test-env environment to install pip (`conda install pip`), so I can install packages with pip, all package I install with pip are installed into the base anaconda environment.

f `which -a pip` returns `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/pip` I've tried adding `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages` to my $PATH variable by executing `export PATH=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages:$PATH` and executing `source ~/.bashrc` but this doesn't even change anything to the result of `which -a pip` (pip installed in my environment is not added), so it still installs my pip packages inside base instead of my environment.

How do I get ubuntu wsl2 to run the correct pip package manager when I activate my environment? Some goes for python, if I run python when my environment is active it references python that is installed in base and not my active environment

Comment: 1. Did you activate the environment with `conda activate test-env` ? 2. `site-packages` should not be in `$PATH`; it's a library directory, not scripts directory. 3. `bin` must be in `$PATH`; try `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.8/bin`

Comment: @phd when I add `/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.8/bin` to PATH and run `which -a pip` again `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/pip` is returned twice instead of once. That is an improvement but still not what I want, because it's the wrong path and package are still installed in base and not in my environment

Comment: `bin` must be **first** in `$PATH` so that `python` and `pip` from the environment are used. The alternative is to run `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip` directly without modifying `$PATH`.